# Table formulas involving percentages

Tags: org-mode, org-table, calc

I'm creating a table with percentages and calculating a simple sum of a column. The only thing left is to show the result of the formula as a percentage.

Here is my MWE:

```
| Element |   $ |
| E1      | 35% |
| E2      | 65% |
|---------+-----|
| Total   |  1. |
#+TBLFM: @>$>=vsum(@2..@-1)
```

My question is: how can I show the result of the formula as `100%` instead of `1`?

The percentage  signs are important because the table will be exported to latex.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would have said: by applying a calc format using the `;<format>` specification described [here](https://orgmode.org/manual/Formula-syntax-for-Calc.html#Formula-syntax-for-Calc) - but I don't know what format that would be. I think [calc can do that](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/calc.html#Percentages) but I don't know if Org mode implements it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error, it seems that something like this might work:

```
| Element |    $ |
|---------+------|
| E1      |  35% |
| E2      |  65% |
|---------+------|
| Total   | 100% |
#+TBLFM: @>$>=vsum(@I..II)*100;%.0f%%
```

You always think of the entries as the corresponding decimal fraction (35% = 35/100 = 0.35 etc) and the result is the sum of the fractions, so you convert the fraction into the percentage by multiplying by 100 and formatting the result as a float with, in this case, 0 digits after the decimal point and appending a % sign (but a % sign has special meaning in format strings so to get a literal percent sign, it needs to be escaped with another percent sign).